# Sorting arrays of intervals in perl?

Tags: perl

I have an array in perl with some intervals like:

> @array = qw(1-5 7-9 10-15 20-58 123-192 234-256)

I am trying to order it using sort but this is what I obtain:

> 1-5  ,  10-15 , 123-192 , 20-58 , 234-256 , 7-9

It is sorted by the first character of the first number... How can be ordered by the whole first number in order to obtain the next array?

> 1-5 , 7-9 , 10-15 , 20-58 , 123-192  , 234-256

Thank you very much!

P.S.

I have no code for this, I am trying the command

```
my @sorted = sort @array;
```

Comment: Would `7-9` come before `7-11`?

Comment: Show the code you have tried. You need to specify your own sorting routine.

Comment: It is not necessary, is not possible that situation in the dataset, but if it is easier to do it in that way there is no problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to extract first number for every element, and do numerical comparison using `<=>` operator,

```
my @array = qw(1-5 7-9 10-15 20-58 123-192 234-256);
my @sorted = sort {
  my ($aa,$bb) = map /^([0-9]+)/, $a,$b; 

  $aa <=> $bb;
} @array;
```

Comment: @mpapec , I almost posted but wasn't fully awake ... now I'm left trying to figure out why `my @sorted = sort {map /^([0-9]+)/, $a,$b ; $a <=> $b } @array;` isn't sufficient (TLP explains part of it).

Comment: @G.Cito I'm not sure what are you referring to; is it second sort criteria?

Comment: @G.Cito TLP uses $a1 and $b1 in that sense. `my ($aa,$cc,$bb,$dd) = map /([0-9]+)/g, $a,$b;` would be to take into account second sort criteria.

Answer (score 6):

What you want to do is sort numerically. To do that, you need to override the default sort method by supplying your own method. This code:

```
my @sorted = sort @array;
```

really means this:

```
my @sorted = sort { $a cmp $b } @array;
```

Where `cmp` is the lexicographical comparison operator (sorts in alphabetic order, more or less). You want to use the `<=>`, often called "the spaceship operator".

```
my @sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @array;
```

But this operator can only be used with numbers, and a string such as `7-9` is not really a number (although in this case it will work, albeit with warnings issued `Argument "7-9" isn't numeric in sort`).

To overcome this warning, and possible bug, we need to extract the numbers from the strings we want to sort. We do this with a regex match: `/\d+/g`. This will match and return all consecutive numbers in the string.

```
my @sorted = sort {
                     my ($a1, $a2) = $a =~ /\d+/g;
                     my ($b1, $b2) = $b =~ /\d+/g;
                     $a1 <=> $b1 || $a2 <=> $b2;
} @array;
```

We capture and use both low and high range, and at the end we perform both checks. This means that in the case that `$a1` and `$b1` are equal, `<=>` returns `0`, and the `||` operator executes the alternate comparison, `$a2 <=> $b2`.

In some cases, this operation is expensive, it takes time, and with a large data set it will cause the sort to become very slow. In this case, we can cache the data using what is known as a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). In this method, we simply store the value of our regex match and use the stored value when sorting. To do this, we use a anonymous array ref `[ ... ]`. At the end we restore the original value and discard the cache:

```
my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }                # restore original
             sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }    # sort compares stored nums
             map  { [ $_, /\d+/g ] }         # store original, and nums
             @array;
```

If you want more than one sort level, you just add `$a->[2] <=> $b->[2]` and so on.

Comment: Very nice answer, I am learning perl and this kind of things are very useful for me, thank you very much!

Comment: "If you want more than one sort level, you just add $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] and so on" is icing on the cake.